# Receiving error in UCM ClearCase while trying to check in an element

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

When I am trying to check in a file in ClearCase, I receive an error:

```
cleartool> ci -nc 1234.txt  
cleartool: Error: Branch not consistent with stream attached to current view.  
cleartool: Error: Unable to check in "1234.txt".
```

Does anyone know what's causing this? It started happening this morning.

So far, I have synchronized the stream and the view with no luck. Please help.

Comment: Now this seems interesting to me:  When I look under version tree of this element, the element checkout is under a branch that is different from the stream the checkout was initiated from??? How can that happen?

Answer (score 1):

> If so, what activity? - tied to a CC activity that is associated to an old stream, CQ activity is tied correctly

That means it is an UCM project with CQ integration.

> When I look under version tree of this element, the element checkout is under a branch that is different from the stream the checkout was initiated from??? How can that happen?

That can only happen if the view used for the checkout had a different config spec than the one generated from the UCM stream. It is best to undo that checkout, and start again in the proper view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I can do is add questions:

1. How old is the checkout?
2. Is it on a NON-UCM branch?
3. If so, when was the component added to the stream's configuration?
4. If you describe the version, is it associated with an activity? If so, what activity?
5. Has anything else "odd" happened to the view of late? (restored view from backup, etc.?)

What you're probably going to need to do is do a ct unco -keep. This will undo the checkout and make the view look at the version selected by the current stream configuration. Then

1. Set an activity
2. Check out the file again
3. Verify that the version created is on the current stream's branch
4. Copy the .keep file to the checked out file
5. Check it in.

Comment: 1.How old is the checkout? - 03/01/16  
2.Is it on a NON-UCM branch? - No, it's UCM stream  
3.If so, when was the component added to the stream's configuration?  
4.If you describe the version, is it associated with an activity? If so, what activity? - tied to a CC activity that is associated to an old stream, CQ activity is tied correctly  
5.Has anything else "odd" happened to the view of late? (restored view from backup, etc.?) - Not that I am aware of

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, just create another new view on required Stream and copy the file into it.